# Update Nexus 9 to Android 7.1 and stuck in Google screen

Tags: boot-loop, nexus-9

I just tried to update my Nexus 9 from Android 7 to 7.1. Unfortunately, the system now seems to be in an endless loop of "Google" screen and black screen (maybe rebooting?). Goes on for hours, nothing happens.

So far, I found out this was a big issue back then for the Android 6 Update - and sometimes the system was so messed up, that the only solution was sending it back to the retailer.

Didn't find anything about the same problem with Android 7.1 - and I hope Google didn't repeat its big mistake here?

Comment: Did you try clearing the cache from recovery ?

Comment: yep, also tried a factory reset - didn't work either